# How to wrap text inside to different paragraphs around image inside the first paragraph (<p> tag). (Content is inputted using CKeditor Plugin)

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR to input content. Whenever user sets image with property right. There is a blank space coming up.
I am having an image inside a

tag. 
My structure is like

```
<p> some text
    <img alt="" src="M.jpg" style="float:right;">
</p>
<p> paragraph 2</p>
```

I want to wrap the paragraph 2 to fill up the white space created by image on paragraph 1.
Is this possible.

My html looks like this
[image: My html looks like this]

I want to make it look like this
[image: I want to make it look like this]

Here is the actual code snippet

```
    <p>Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups under<img alt="" src="/media/uploads/2018/09/27/sufs5o_fWCbPPM.jpg" style="float:right; height:1080px; width:420px">Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. .</p>

<p>s settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.</p>
```

Comment: style="float:right;> you are missing the closing double quotes.

Comment: this is used just for representation only. This will be content from CKeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your effort. I found that the issue was there in the CSS.
there was `overflow: hidden;` property defined for the `<p>` tag. Commenting it has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just give style to `img` tag. Also, write your paragraph content after `img` tag so it can wrap around the image.

CSS Code-

```
img{
    float: right;
}
```

You can also try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdp6xfa3/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
div.floatright {
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
}

.floatright {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.2em 0 0.8em 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:justify;margin:6px">
<div class="floatright">
<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Mandala1_detail.jpg/150px-Mandala1_detail.jpg" width="150" height="173">
</div>
<p>
El arte budista tiene su origen en el subcontinente indio (actuales India, Bangladés, Nepal y Pakistán) en los siglos posteriores a la vida de Siddhartha Gautama, el Buda histórico, entre los siglos vi y v a. C. Más tarde, gracias al contacto con otras culturas, logró evolucionar y difundirse por el resto de Asia y el mundo.

Una primera etapa, llamada preicónica, se sitúa antes del siglo i d. C. y se caracteriza por no recurrir a representaciones directas de Siddhartha Gautama como el Buda Śākyamuni o de los budas míticos que se suponen existieron en eras pasadas. La etapa siguiente, icónica, tiene por el contrario a la imagen humana del Buda y los budas del pasado, del futuro y de otros universos como símbolo central de sus obras de arte.

Desde entonces, el arte budista se diversificó y evolucionó para adaptarse a las nuevas regiones en las que comenzaba a sumar adeptos. Se expandió hacia el este y el norte a través de Asia Central, para formar lo que luego fue clasificado como arte budista del norte —en contraposición al arte budista del sur, que surgiría en el sudeste de Asia. En India, el arte budista floreció e incluso llegó a influir en el desarrollo del arte hindú, hasta que el budismo casi desapareció alrededor del siglo x, con la expansión del hinduismo y el islam.
</p>
<p>
El arte budista tiene su origen en el subcontinente indio (actuales India, Bangladés, Nepal y Pakistán) en los siglos posteriores a la vida de Siddhartha Gautama, el Buda histórico, entre los siglos vi y v a. C. Más tarde, gracias al contacto con otras culturas, logró evolucionar y difundirse por el resto de Asia y el mundo.

Una primera etapa, llamada preicónica, se sitúa antes del siglo i d. C. y se caracteriza por no recurrir a representaciones directas de Siddhartha Gautama como el Buda Śākyamuni o de los budas míticos que se suponen existieron en eras pasadas. La etapa siguiente, icónica, tiene por el contrario a la imagen humana del Buda y los budas del pasado, del futuro y de otros universos como símbolo central de sus obras de arte.

Desde entonces, el arte budista se diversificó y evolucionó para adaptarse a las nuevas regiones en las que comenzaba a sumar adeptos. Se expandió hacia el este y el norte a través de Asia Central, para formar lo que luego fue clasificado como arte budista del norte —en contraposición al arte budista del sur, que surgiría en el sudeste de Asia. En India, el arte budista floreció e incluso llegó a influir en el desarrollo del arte hindú, hasta que el budismo casi desapareció alrededor del siglo x, con la expansión del hinduismo y el islam.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Float right for the image will do.

## or

Try switching the image first before the text. follow as bellow

see this one: https://jsfiddle.net/xeqncj9h/1/

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iusto totam, excepturi molestias ab est eos, quam cumque, animi culpa numquam quaerat voluptatibus et voluptate quia omnis nemo ex qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni iusto totam, excepturi molestias ab est eos, quam cumque, animi culpa numquam quaerat voluptatibus et voluptate quia omnis nemo ex qui.</p>

<p class=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here the paragraphs and image is the output from ckeditor plugin. So the image may not be always of type float right

Comment: Try these [link](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/18784-wrapping-text-around-image-ckeditor/) and [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151715/how-to-wrap-the-text-in-source-view-of-ckeditor) maybe it can help you. @SudheerK

Answer (score 1):

```
<img align="right"  hspace="3px" vspace="3px" src="M.jpg"" >
```

Add align="right" also can achieve our effect

"hspace" and "vspace" let us add more space between img and text.