# When a image is right aligned, text of below paragraphs is not wrapping around Image in html page. But wraps inside the Text area of CKeditor

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor to input RichText. 
Inside the text area of CKEditor, the text is perfectly wrapped over the image. 
But the text is not wraping on the html page.

This is how it looks in CKeditor
[image]

But my html looks like this.
[image]

What may be I am missing here. ?
Here is the actual code snippet

```
 <p>Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups under
    <img alt="" src="/media/uploads/2018/09/27/sufs5o_fWCbPPM.jpg" style="float:right; height:1080px; width:420px">
Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. .
</p>

    <p>s settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.Enter each item on a new line, choose the amount of groups unders settings, and click the button to generate your randomized list. Don't like the first team? Just click again until you do.Fairly pick teams without bias. No need to draw names out of a hat. No need to do a grade school style draft or put hours of thought into the most balanced teams. The most fair dividing method possible is random.</p>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52658554/10283047

Comment: Please don’t ask what is essentially the same question twice, especially not with just one hour between them.

Comment: I was getting  answers that was not related. Thats why I added another question that makes sense

Comment: That is not a good justification for a duplicate. If the answers you are getting are not what you want or need, then you should deal with that there, by telling people why.

Comment: can you help me to close or delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img align="right" hspace="3px" vspace="3px"  alt="" src="/media/uploads/2018/09/27/sufs5o_fWCbPPM.jpg" style="height:1080px; width:420px">
```

Try this on

Answer (score 0):

```css
.floatright {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:justify;margin:6px">

<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Mandala1_detail.jpg/150px-Mandala1_detail.jpg" width="150" height="173"
class="floatright"
>

<p>
El arte budista tiene su origen en el subcontinente indio (actuales India, Bangladés, Nepal y Pakistán) en los siglos posteriores a la vida de Siddhartha Gautama, el Buda histórico, entre los siglos vi y v a. C. Más tarde, gracias al contacto con otras culturas, logró evolucionar y difundirse por el resto de Asia y el mundo.

Una primera etapa, llamada preicónica, se sitúa antes del siglo i d. C. y se caracteriza por no recurrir a representaciones directas de Siddhartha Gautama como el Buda Śākyamuni o de los budas míticos que se suponen existieron en eras pasadas. La etapa siguiente, icónica, tiene por el contrario a la imagen humana del Buda y los budas del pasado, del futuro y de otros universos como símbolo central de sus obras de arte.

Desde entonces, el arte budista se diversificó y evolucionó para adaptarse a las nuevas regiones en las que comenzaba a sumar adeptos. Se expandió hacia el este y el norte a través de Asia Central, para formar lo que luego fue clasificado como arte budista del norte —en contraposición al arte budista del sur, que surgiría en el sudeste de Asia. En India, el arte budista floreció e incluso llegó a influir en el desarrollo del arte hindú, hasta que el budismo casi desapareció alrededor del siglo x, con la expansión del hinduismo y el islam.
</p>
<p>
El arte budista tiene su origen en el subcontinente indio (actuales India, Bangladés, Nepal y Pakistán) en los siglos posteriores a la vida de Siddhartha Gautama, el Buda histórico, entre los siglos vi y v a. C. Más tarde, gracias al contacto con otras culturas, logró evolucionar y difundirse por el resto de Asia y el mundo.

Una primera etapa, llamada preicónica, se sitúa antes del siglo i d. C. y se caracteriza por no recurrir a representaciones directas de Siddhartha Gautama como el Buda Śākyamuni o de los budas míticos que se suponen existieron en eras pasadas. La etapa siguiente, icónica, tiene por el contrario a la imagen humana del Buda y los budas del pasado, del futuro y de otros universos como símbolo central de sus obras de arte.

Desde entonces, el arte budista se diversificó y evolucionó para adaptarse a las nuevas regiones en las que comenzaba a sumar adeptos. Se expandió hacia el este y el norte a través de Asia Central, para formar lo que luego fue clasificado como arte budista del norte —en contraposición al arte budista del sur, que surgiría en el sudeste de Asia. En India, el arte budista floreció e incluso llegó a influir en el desarrollo del arte hindú, hasta que el budismo casi desapareció alrededor del siglo x, con la expansión del hinduismo y el islam.
</p>
</div>
```